# Accessing localhost from android browser

Tags: android, apache, wamp, wampserver

I am using WAMP(version 2.4.9) to host a local server on my pc. My pc is connected to wifi and the ip address is 10.192.31.222 . The port is 3333. When I type `http://10.192.31.222:3333/` in the browser of pc, I get the wampserver homepage as it should be but when I type in the same address in my mobile browser, I get the following error

```
Forbidden 
You don't have permission to access / on this server
```

I have connected both my pc and mobile over same wifi network. I have set "Require all granted" in httpd.conf file and looked all the solution on internet. Please help.

Comment: Unlock port 3333 on firewall to be accessible from your mobile device.

Comment: Yes , I think I did it. I followed following steps: Control panel >> Windows Firewall> Advanced settings(on left pane) >> Inbound rules >> New rules. Then a new popup window came. I selected "port" then entered 3333 in specific local port, then selected "allow the connection", then selected all the three "domain", "private" and "public" check boxes and finally gave name "port3333" and clicked finish

Comment: When I use IIS on Windows I have problems with it. Read this [blog](http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer)

Comment: Sorry but I don't have anything called IIS in my computer. Please tell what to do.